# Azure deployment fails due to startup script

Tags: deployment, azure, startupscript

I'm kicking off the startup script per the following in my ServiceDefinition.csdef

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe install" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
  <Task commandLine="startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
</Startup>
```

The startup.cmd file is

```
@echo off
REM StartupLog.txt can be found at (E or F):\approot\bin

Echo Copying MyUtil to system root                                                        >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
copy /y MyUtil.exe %SystemRoot%                                                           >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ErrorExit

REM It's ok if the next fails, the task may not be scheduled 1st time
Echo Trying to delete MyUtil from scheduler                                               >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
schtasks /Delete /F /TN "MyUtil"                                                          >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1

Echo Adding MyUtil to Scheduler                                                           >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
schtasks /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 2 /SD 11/01/2012 /TN "MyUtil" /TR %SystemRoot%\MyUtil.exe >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ErrorExit                                                            >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
GOTO End

:ErrorExit
REM   Report the date, time, and ERRORLEVEL of the error.
%ERRORLEVEL%                                                      >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
DATE /T                                                           >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
TIME /T                                                           >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
ECHO An error occurred during startup. ERRORLEVEL = %ERRORLEVEL%  >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
ECHO -----------------------------------------------------------  >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
EXIT /B 1

:End    
ECHO Exiting at end with 0                                        >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
ECHO -----------------------------------------------------------  >> StartupLog.txt 2>&1
EXIT /B 0
```

The error in (E: or F:)\approot\bin is :

```
Copying MyUtil to system root                                                        
        1 file(s) copied.
Trying to delete MyUtil from scheduler                                                
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "MyUtil" was successfully deleted.
Adding MyUtil to Scheduler                                                            
ERROR: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

(43,4):LogonType:'1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I run the startup.cmd file after RDPing into the WebRole then the tasks get added to the scheduler just fine. For some reason it always fails through deployment. Does anyone know how to fix this? I reverted to OSVersion=2 till I can fix this issue.

Comment: What is the **ERRORLEVEL**? You should [output it to a log file `>> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974418.aspx)

Comment: Weirdly enough, nothing gets written to the StartupLog.txt. When I RDP into the machine %TEMP% is `D:\Users\<RDP_User>\AppData\Local\Temp\2`. I searched the entire VM for `StartupLog.txt` - nothing!

Answer (score 0):

The reason probably is that the user executing your script does not (yet) have an AppData directory. Can you try adding these at the top of your startup task?

```
md "%~dp0appdata"
reg add "hku\.default\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\user shell folders" /v "Local AppData" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%~dp0appdata" /f
```

Comment: Doesn't help, still no output and script still fails. I know ErrorLevel!=0 since a usual deploy of 11 minutes is on for ~1 hour. I also upgraded the OSFamily=3, so we're on Windows (Azure) Server 2012, but the issue is still the same. Any idea under which account the startup script runs? The RDP user? I need a faster way to trigger the startup script exec than a full redeploy to debug this rapidly ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and after wasting several hours thinking it was a permissions problem, it turned out that it wanted double quotes around the path specified as the /TR parameter. Actually I had command line parameters, so  I needed to specify it like "\"appname.exe\" \"parameter\""

Like you, I was using environment variables in my task - this may be relevant although I'm not sure why. Also like you, the task ran fine when launched as my RDP user, it just failed when run as the actual startup task under SYSTEM.

I know a few months have past so you may have moved on from this issue, but I'm curious as to whether the quotes also fixes the problem for you (and for bonus points, an explanation of why it cares!).